# Read MIDI data from Akai MPK mini mkII USB MIDI controller to AVR

Tags: avr, midi

I have experience with AVR controllers and now I am developing analog synth like sound module. I would like to be able to connect a USB midi controller to my sound box. I would like to use an AVR microcontroller and I think my option is either to buy a USB to MIDI adapter for the keyboard and build an AVR MIDI interface or use something like an FT232RL chip for USB and code for reading MIDI commands. I would like to hear suggestions from more experienced engineers.

Comment: While English may not be your first language, please try to spell check and use proper capitalization to the best of your ability. It greatly increases readability.

Answer (score 1):

USB MIDI is a different protocol that is not supported by the FT232R.
You would need to use a general-purpose microcontroller with USB support.

Furthermore, USB makes a strict distinction between hosts and devices, and your controller is a USB device, which can be connected only to a USB host.

So you would need to use a board with a USB host (or OTG) controller, such as the Raspberry Pi. Alternatively, pay for the [Kenton USB MIDI Host](http://www.kentonuk.com/products/items/utilities/usb-host.shtml), or connect both the controller and your AVR board to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

To add to CL.'s excellent answer: Creating a USB host that supports USB MIDI is not trivial. Either use a computer in between, or get a keyboard that supports "real" (hardware) MIDI output, which is *very* easy to interface with the microcontroller of your choice. The Akai MPK 25 would be an excellent choice, for instance.

Edit: after further research for another project, I've realized that creating a USB MIDI host device may be easier than I thought. A MAX3421E can be used to implement a fairly inexpensive USB MIDI host. For a "just add water"-product, get yourself the USB Host Shield for your Arduino, which has a MAX3421E. You should be able to find a library supporting USB MIDI, and you can relatively easily build a USB-MIDI to hardware MIDI converter.

Comment: What if I don't have possibility to buy another keyboard? Maybe usb to midi adapter would do?

Comment: Yes, you can go keyboard to computer via USB, and computer to Arduino via USB-MIDI cable, if you're OK with the computer in the middle.

Comment: This options is viable for me, but how will USB Midi keyboard passthrough computer to my AVR MIDI device?

Comment: You simply need a piece of software that can route a MIDI input (your keyboard) to a MIDI output (the USB-MIDI cable). Numerous pieces of software exist for your operating system of choice.

Comment: @user112290 See my edit, I've changed my answer after some research.

Comment: MAX3421E  looks like a good option. It would help implement my AVR as USB host device to read MIDI notes from USB midi device?

Comment: Yes, it should.